# CORS problem when accessing rest endpoint with angular client - cross origin is allowed

Tags: java, angular, spring, http, kotlin

So I have a strange situation. Some weeks ago I was accessing rest endpoints from my spring backend via angular It worked, after I added `@CrossOrigin(origins = arrayOf("http://localhost:4200"))` on top of the controller classes.

However, after adding some Spring security and some http interceptor on the client, it stopped working, saying

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/backend/calculationtype/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy`

I dont know how this could happen. After authorization I am getting a Bearer Token, which I add to the httpHeader via Interceptor. When using Postman, everything works fine. I am using OAuth2.

I will show some classes.

token.interceptor.ts:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.temp.getToken()}` //contains the Bearer token
      }
    });
    console.log(request);
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

I am using `console.log` to print the request which I am sending. The header of the request contains the key `Authorization` with the value `Bearer e23..........`. Using those values in postman, it is working.

CalculationTypeController.kt (I am using kotlin instead of java):

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = arrayOf("http://localhost:4200")) //this line worked before
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ["v1/backend/calculationtype/"])
class CalculationTypeController() {

    @RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.POST], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun addCalculationType(@RequestBody calcDTO: CalcDTO): CalcuDTO {
       
        some stuff happening...
    }
}
```

When using authentication, I had to add a `proxy.conf.json` but I didnt need it to get my data from the endpoints. However, here it is.

proxy.conf.json:

```
{
    "/oauth/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin":true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    },
    "/v1/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin":true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
}
}
```

Who can give me some advice or tell me whats going on here? Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you added the `proxy.config` in the angular.json:

```json
...
"serve": {
  "proxyConfig": "proxy.config.js"
}
...
```

proxy.config.js

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
  "context": ['/oauth/*']
  "target": "http://localhost:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin":true,
  "logLevel": "debug"
  },
  {
  "context": ['/v1/backend']
  "target": "http://localhost:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin":true,
  "logLevel": "debug"
  },
]
```

Comment: interesting solution but sadly it didnt make a difference

Comment: did you restart the angular server?

Comment: yeah, using npm start

Comment: Well that's strange. I use exactly that for different ports in my project. ...and I didn't read that you are already using a proxy.config. I assume this cfg is for angular, right? Please add the backend url in the proxy.config. And remove the proxy attribute from the package.json

Comment: okay I did the changes. I updated my post with a new proxy.conf.json but the error did not change. Did I do something wrong in it? I am trying to access rest endpoint `http://localhost:8080/v1/backend/calculationtype/` using POST

Comment: I edited my answer with my `proxy.config.js`. Notice I am using **.js** not **.json** in case you will copy it.

Comment: I have multiple endpoints under `http:localhost:8080/v1/backend/`. What shall I write in `BackendURL:PORT`?

Comment: just the root http:localhost:8080. How do the request urls in the angular app look like? `host/v1/backend/*****` ?

Comment: thanks - no I use the full path `http://localhost:8080/v1/backend/calculationtype/` for example

Comment: okay I guess all of your routes are prefix with `/v1/backend/`. If you add `http://localhost:8080` as target and `/v1/backend` as context then you should be able to request your backend with the following route schema: `http.post('/v1/backend/calculationtype/')`

Comment: If that doesnt do the trick then please send my a pasebin with your proxy.config.js, angular.json(just the serve part is enough), and the service/compoent that does the http.post request. Maybe it's a typo and you looked at it so much that you got blind :D

Comment: dafuq, I just made a comment but it is not showing anywhere. However, it works now! Thank you so much! But why did it work some while ago with the full path and now it only works with the relative path?

Comment: GREAT! In my case it is always because of cors issues.

Comment: I'm gald I could help :). May I ask you for the green check. Grinding for rep here :P

Comment: yeah, you deserve it :) but one thing doesnt make much sense to me. In the proxy.conf.json I just redirect requests to `localhost:8080`. This works. But isnt it the same if I delete that stuff from the proxy.conf.json and simply use the full path like `http.post("http://localhost:8080/v1/backend/calculationtype")` instead of the now working request `http.post("/v1/backend/calculationtype")`?

Comment: Well your angular app runs at localhost:4200 and your backend at localhost:8080. That are to different origins and therefor the cors policy doesn't allow the request. Using the proxy tricks the app that both host are the same origin. More on that [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85). I saw that the other answers suggested some cors settings. Maybe they are not applying for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try enable CORS for your project, create this class in your Spring project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Or incase you got Spring Boot app:

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Both classes are  `@Configuration` so they will be running as part of the app server start

Comment: I added it to my SecurityConfig class, but nothing changed

Comment: This answer doesn't resolve the OP's problem. @IonicMan already have CORS setup via `@CrossOrigin` which is the alternative for what you described but in the scope of a single controller. See the corresponding section in [Spring MVC docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-cors-processing).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring Security, you need to perform some additional steps. Otherwise, Spring Security will reject the request before it reaches Spring MVC.

See [the related section in Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors) for details.

Comment: damn, added it but still no difference

Comment: I gather it was a complex problem in both frontend and backend. Sorry, cannot say much about the angular part. Glad you've eventually found the solution)